# can you explain why changing a class' function attribute has the following effect?

Tags: python

consider the code below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data    

    def f(self):
        print('from A', self.data)

a = A(20)

def fnew(self):
    print('new from A', self.data)

A.f = fnew
print(a.f.__func__ is A.f)
```

the output is True, but i expected it to be false. here is why: from what i understand, each time an object O is created from class C it inherits all of the function attributes of C in the form of objects with type 'method'. each such method object has as attributes O and the corresponding function. in this case a.f has attributes the object a and the function with name 'f'. but when A.f = fnew is executed i am only changing the attributes of the class object A, not the attributes of the method object a.f, so how come a.f.**func** is changed at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `a.f`, Python will look up the member `f` from the instance `a`. When it cannot find a member with that name, it will look up the type hierarchy to find it. So in this case, it will look at the instance’s type, which is `A`. That’s why accessing `a.f` will use the function that is stored in `A.f`.

If you were to overwrite `f` in the instance, this would not happen:

```
>>> A.f = fnew
>>> a.f
<bound method fnew of <__main__.A object at 0x00000083E819B1D0>>
>>> a.f = 'foo'
>>> a.f
'foo
```

Note that when creating an instance, members from the type will *not* be copied down to the instance. If that were to happen, that would make creating instances of objects very expensive. Instead, the type system will just look up members from the type when the instance does not have the member on its own.

---

As noted by timgeb in the comments, in Python 2, your final check `a.f.__func__ is A.f` will return `False`. This is because there, `A.f` will return an *unbound* function which is not the same as the original function. But that’s just a minor detail that will not change anything about what I wrote above: The method will still be looked up from the type.

Comment: Note that OP's `print` acutally gives `False` in Python 2. Maybe a complete answer should touch on that fact.

Comment: when i execute print(dir(a)), i see f appearing, so how is f not copied into a? i am assuming dir(a) lists all of the attributes of the object, maybe that is incorrect?

Comment: @timgeb Added a note about that, although that’s not really that important here.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев `dir(a)` will list all attributes of `a` and its type. If you only want to see the attributes that actually exist on the instance object itself, you should take a look at `a.__dict__`.